# Save output document in php

Tags: php

I am trying to save the output document in a folder on the server when using php. The code saves it to my computer but I need to save the file inside a folder with a name.

Please check the code:

```
// Save File
$h2d_file_uri = tempnam('', 'htd');
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($phpword_object, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($h2d_file_uri);

// Download the file:
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=example.docx');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($h2d_file_uri));
ob_clean();
flush();
$status = readfile($h2d_file_uri);
unlink($h2d_file_uri);
exit;
```

I tried file_put_contents('test.txt', file_get_contents('http://web.com')); but it did not help me. Please tell me how do I save the file in a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use this code to save your output in a folder with a name just provide a folder name and file name 
  $fileName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/download/muraripradip.docx';
  $objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($phpword_object, 'Word2007');

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are doing a lot of stuff that you don't need. Unless you want to download the file, you can skip all the code from:

```
// Download the file: - And below that point
```

It looks like you could just alter the existing code a little:

Turn this code:

```
// Save File
$h2d_file_uri = tempnam('', 'htd');
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($phpword_object, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($h2d_file_uri);
```

Into this:

```
// Save File
$h2d_file_uri = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/docs/some_file_name.docx';
$objWriter = PHPWord_IOFactory::createWriter($phpword_object, 'Word2007');
$objWriter->save($h2d_file_uri);
```

If will then be saved into the http://domian.tld/docs/some_file_name.docx folder. You could save it somewhere the public is not allowed to access.